# Error in VS2019 with Google Test when using outside definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest, lnk2019

I just started a small console app in VS2019 and added a Google Test project. The program itself compiles and runs fine, however, if I move function code from the header to the cpp-file, I get the LNK2019 and LNK1120 errors:

| Severity | Code | Description | Project | File | Line |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Error | LNK2019 | unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl MyClass::someFunction(void)" (?someFunction@MyClass@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl MyTests_basicTest_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@MyTests_basicTest_Test@@EEAAXXZ) | Tests | Tests.obj | 1 |
| Error | LNK1120 | 1 unresolved externals | Tests | Tests.exe | 1 |

**MyClass.h**:

```
#pragma once
class MyClass
{
public:
  void someFunction();
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
void MyClass::someFunction() {
  // do something
}
```

**Main.cpp**:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
  MyClass mc;
  mc.someFunction();
}
```

**Tests.cpp**:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "../TestApp/MyClass.h"

TEST(MyTests, basicTest) {
  MyClass mc;
  mc.someFunction();
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

I could just put all of the code in the header file of course, but I don't think that is what I'm supposed to do, so I would greatly appreciate some help on this.

**Edit**:
I feel like I'm one step closer (though it is only a shot in the dark): I added the directory that contains all the *.obj files under [Tests Project] -> "Properties" -> "Configuration Properties" -> "Linker" -> "Input" -> "Additional Dependencies": `D:\Application\x64\Debug`

However, now I get the following error:

> LNK1104    cannot open file 'D:\Application\x64\Debug.obj'

And indeed, the directory contains all kinds of obj-files but not `Debug.obj`. :/

**Edit 2**:
Solved! I followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-microsoft-test-framework-for-cpp?view=vs-2019#object_files) under *"To link the tests to the object or library files"*. Important that you really just enter the base name of the file itself without the ".obj".

Comment: How are you building your tests?

Comment: Do you know how the build process in C/C++ works? I think you are not linking against any library to test, also you cannot test an executable like you created

Comment: @loic.lopez: I open the Test Explorer and press "Run All Tests In View".

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: No, not really. I know that the files are linked and intermediary obj-files are created, but not much more than that. What puzzles me that it works when I have all the code in the header and only fails once I move it outside.